# How to reduce height of Combobox component in Ext js 6.0.2?

Tags: extjs6-classic

I am using Extjs6.0.2 and I want to reduce the height of combobox. 
As show in below image , I was not able to reduce the height of combobox.
[image: Combobox]

Following is my code :

```
                name : 'opcode',
                allowBlank : false,
                blankText : 'Please Select Opcode',
                xtype : 'combo',
                emptyText : ' ',
                queryMode : 'local',
                padding:'0 50 5 10',
                width : 200,
                height:10, 
                id : 'id_xxx',
                displayField : 'value',
                valueField : 'key',
                store : xxx,
                matchFieldWidth: false
```

Can you please help me to reduce this combobox size in extjs 6?

Regards

Comment: you mean you want it thinner?

Comment: Yes I need to make it thinner to match with other applications

Comment: you need to add a css class to it

Comment: are you using a specific sencha theme or it is a personal one? please add a simple fiddle to show us what is your current situation and css

Comment: I am using sencha theme Neptune theme classic .